# Terraspace Bundle: ERROR: There was a git error - fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: terraform, terraspace

When I run `terraspace bundle` I see the following error message:

```
Bundling with Terrafile...
ERROR: There was a git error
Current dir: /private/tmp/terraspace/bundler/cache/github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-cloudfront-s3-cdn
The error occur when running:
git pull 2>&1
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Only certain modules in my Terrafile seem to have this issue as I am able to bypass the problem by commenting those failing modules out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to try `rm -rf /private/tmp/terraspace/bundler/cache/<module>` on each of the failing modules.

After I did so the modules installed correctly:

```
Bundling with Terrafile...
Exporting aws-iam-role
Exporting ecr
Exporting iam-system-user
Exporting s3-cdn
Modules saved to vendor/modules
```

I am uncertain of the root cause of the corrupted cache.